# Reduce if-else loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Is there any way to reduce the following function?

```
def treefix(p):
    if p.parent:
        if p.parent.size==1:
            treefix(p.parent)
        else:
            p.children=[]
            sizefix(p)
    else:
        p.children=[]
        sizefix(p)
```

I tried the following but it didn't work the same way.

```
def treefix(p):
    if p.parent:
        if p.parent.size==1:
            treefix(p.parent)
    p.children=[]
    sizefix(p)
```

Comment: Add a `return` statement after `treefix(p.parent)`

Comment: `if` is not a loop. Why do so many beginners call it a loop? A loop is something that repeats -- isn't the metaphor obvious?

Comment: My advice would be to draw a diagram. It will help to identify the best if-else structure that will cover all possibilities. Could you please draw a diagram so we all can understand better what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def treefix(p):
    if p.parent and p.parent.size == 1:
        treefix(p.parent)
    else:
        p.children=[]
        sizefix(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

As another answer points out, the simplification you need is just:

```
def treefix(p):
    if p.parent and p.parent.size == 1:
        treefix(p.parent)
    else:
        p.children=[]
        sizefix(p)
```

The code in the question will avoid evaluating `p.parent.size==1` in the event that `p.parent` has a value that yields False.  This may be important, because for example if `p.parent` has the value `None`, then trying to evaluate `p.parent.size` would raise an `AttributeError`.

However, despite possible appearances, the same *also* is true with the simplified `and` expression shown here, because of **short-circuit evaluation**.

Specifically, the second operand (i.e. after the `and`) will be evaluated *only if* the first operand (i.e. before the `and`) yields True.  If the first operand yields False, then the whole `and` expression will evaluate to the value of the first operand *without the right-hand operand ever being evaluated*.

Only if the first operand yields True, the result of the `and` operation will be the value of the second operand.

So the ordering here is important, and it would **not** work to write:

```
    if p.parent.size == 1 and p.parent:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return`

```
def treefix(p):
    if p.parent:
        if p.parent.size==1:
            treefix(p.parent)
            return
    p.children=[]
    sizefix(p)
```